# multiprocessing.SimpleQueue hangs when given too many items

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to test the performance of `multiprocessing.SimpleQueue` compared to `multiprocessing.Queue`, so I made the following program:

```py
import multiprocessing as MP
import time


def worker_func(job_queue: MP.Queue, result_queue: MP.Queue):
    count = 0
    while True:
        job = job_queue.get()
        result_queue.put(f"Got job {job}")
        if job == "DIE":
            result_queue.put("FIN")
            print("X", end="", flush=True)
            break
        if count % 100 == 0:
            print("+", end="", flush=True)
        count += 1
    job_queue.close()
    result_queue.close()


def test_queue(queue_factory, job_num: int = 100_000):
    workers_count = 2
    workers = []

    jobq = queue_factory()
    resq = queue_factory()
    for _ in range(0, workers_count):
        p = MP.Process(target=worker_func, args=(jobq, resq))
        p.start()
        workers.append(p)

    time.sleep(1.0)

    start_t = time.monotonic()
    print(f"Sending {job_num:,} jobs ... ", end="", flush=True)
    for i in range(0, job_num):
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print(".", end="", flush=True)
        jobq.put(i)
    print("Jobs sent, killing ... ", end="", flush=True)
    for _ in workers:
        jobq.put("DIE")
    print("Signals sent ... ", end="", flush=True)
    while not jobq.empty():
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print("jobq emptied ... ", end="", flush=True)
    finished = 0
    while not resq.empty() or finished < workers_count:
        if resq.get() == "FIN":
            finished += 1
    jobq.close()
    resq.close()
    elapsed_t = time.monotonic() - start_t
    [w.join() for w in workers]
    print(f" Elapsed time: {elapsed_t:,.2f}")
    return elapsed_t


if __name__ == '__main__':
    joblen = 10_000
    print("MP.Queue")
    for _ in range(0, 5):
        test_queue(MP.Queue, joblen)
    print("MP.SimpleQueue")
    for _ in range(0, 5):
        test_queue(MP.SimpleQueue, joblen)
```

The program works if I set `joblen` to `100` or `200`.

But if I set `joblen` to, say, `10_000`, it got stuck. The output looks like this:

```
MP.Queue
Sending 10,000 jobs ... .+.........Jobs sent, killing ... Signals sent ... jobq emptied ... ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++XX Elapsed time: 0.61
Sending 10,000 jobs ... .+...+......Jobs sent, killing ... Signals sent ... +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++XXjobq emptied ...  Elapsed time: 0.88
Sending 10,000 jobs ... .++.........Jobs sent, killing ... Signals sent ... jobq emptied ... +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++XX Elapsed time: 0.66
Sending 10,000 jobs ... .+..+.......Jobs sent, killing ... Signals sent ... +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++XXjobq emptied ...  Elapsed time: 0.75
Sending 10,000 jobs ... .+.........Jobs sent, killing ... Signals sent ... jobq emptied ... ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++XX Elapsed time: 0.61
MP.SimpleQueue
Sending 10,000 jobs ... .++++
```

As you can see, it seems stuck trying to `.put()` an item into the `SimpleQueue`.

Is there an inherent limit to the number of outstanding (not-consumed) items in `SimpleQueue`? Or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After doing lots of searches, I found [Bug 41550](https://bugs.python.org/issue41550).

It seems `SimpleQueue` uses `os.pipe`, which has limited capacity (64k iirc). So if `resq` is not consumed regularly, it will block.

The solution for my purpose is to add yet one more worker whose function is none other than consuming `resq`.